# How to update an integer array element in Mongo DB using Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

[image: This is our document in MongoDB]

We need to update the latitude coordinate (address.coord[0]) whose value is less than 50.
How to build the query to do this using Spring Data. The following few snippets show the methods we tried.

**The below one do the update but it removes coord-0(latitude) and coord-1(longitude)**

```
Criteria c = where("address.coord").lt(value);
Update update = new Update().set("address.coord", value);
WriteResult result = mongodb.updateMulti(query(c), update, "restaurants");
```

**The below one could't even able to find the documents matching the criteria**

```
Criteria c = where("address.$.coord").lt(value);
Update update = new Update().set("address.$.coord", value);
WriteResult result = mongodb.updateMulti(query(c), update, "restaurants");
```

Thanks in advance for your valuable answers

Comment: `Criteria c = where("address.coord.0").lt(value); Update update = new Update().set("address.coord.0", value); WriteResult result = mongodb.updateMulti(query(c), update, "restaurants");`

Comment: `"address.$.coord"` implies address is an array which is not the case hence the query which uses this fails.

Comment: @Veeram I tried that too, I got the same result as that of in my second code snippet. It updated the address.coord[0] but I lost address.cord[1]

Comment: Sorry didn't realize `address` was not a embedded array and `coord` is. Something like `Criteria c = where("address.coord").lt(value);
Update update = new Update().set("address.coord.$", value);
WriteResult result = mongodb.updateMulti(query(c), update, "restaurants");`

Comment: @chridam it worked. Thanks, Chridam and Veeram

Answer (score 1):

```
 Criteria c = where("address.coord.0").lt(value); 
 Update update = new Update().set("address.coord.0", value);
 WriteResult result = mongodb.updateMulti(query(c), update, "restaurants");
```

> address.coord.0